# How do I Know My System Available Gradle buildToolsVersion

Tags: android, gradle

This issue is encountered when my Android Studio project is copied by others, but they can'r run it directly.
The error message is `failed to find build tools versions XX.X.X`. 
Then how do they know what the version should be changed for their own system?
Or is there a better way to set the `buildToolsVersion "XX.X.X"` to widely suit others in `build.gradle`?
Also the same question for `compileSdkVersion`, how do I know the version(s) available in my system?
Is there a gradle(not limited) script to find out the available version?

Comment: what build tool version are you using? I ran into this with 23.x.xr3

Comment: @NoahHerron I am using 22.0.1, but more are available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your `build.gradle (Module:<app-name>)` file. There should be a `buildToolsVersion` line in that file. Make sure that you and others have that version of the build tools installed.

Also make sure that the version of build tools is still available form the SDK manager.

I had this issue when working on a friend's project. He was using a version of build tools that I could not get anymore. I think this is because things are updated and replaced.

We fixed this by both installing the most current version of build tools.

I have also ran into this issue when I upgraded Android Studios and the version of build tools was no longer available.

For the `compileSdkVersion` you can goto `Tools > Android > SDK Manager`. This will pull up a window that will allow you to manage your `compileSdkVersion` and your `buildToolsVersion`.

You can also select the link at the bottom left (Launch Standalone SDK Manager) this will give you a little bit more information.

Comment: Thank you, I can find that from `Android SDK Manager`, I am wondering can we got the info with gradle script?

Answer (score 6):

On Linux you'll find your BuildTool Versions on :

`$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/`

Answer (score 3):

You can check the available versions from the official android developer's link : https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html

Then choose the corresponding version (*generally the latest*) based on your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`